# Converting HEX string into int

Tags: python, sql, hex, floating-point-conversion, varbinarymax

I need help on converting the varbinary data which I acquired from sql, into int by taking 4 bits at a time.
From the code above, I acquired the results as ('0x640761075D075A0.....'). My plan is to take every 4 bits & swap it (ex: 0764 0761 07D5 and so on) and then turn every 4 bits into integers. what should I do?
thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
from struct import pack, unpack

def convert_hex_to_int(n:int, interval:int):
    splitted = [hex(n)[2:][i:i+interval] for i in range(0, len(hex(n)[2:]), interval)]
    return [unpack('<H', pack('>H', int(i, 16)))[0] for i in splitted]

print(convert_hex_to_int(0x640761075D07, 4))
```

It will return `list` of `int`: `[1892, 1889, 1885]`

Comment: Hi, thankyou ! if i change to floating point, what should i do?

Comment: What does floating point mean? I know that floating point is used for represent `float` number, but i cannot find where the `float` number is. Please tell me with other words...

Comment: I meant float, to make the result to be 1892.00, 1889.00,..

Comment: ok, then just cast `float()` to return values like: `return [float(int(hex(unpack('<H', pack('>H', int(i, 16)))[0]), 16)) for i in splitted]`. Then you will get `[1892.0, 1889.0, 1885.0]`.

Comment: Maybe you cannot represent `1892.0` by `1892.00`, but it is available to convert to `'1892.00'` by using `'%.2f' % 1892`.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help! But do you mind telling me why there are a lot of converting between HEX to int then back to hex then to int again and so on? Thank you very much

Comment: That was just my mistake. Thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: oh no, but that works!

Comment: The previous one is `int(hex(unpack('<H', pack('>H', int(i, 16)))[0]), 16)`, but this is same as `unpack('<H', pack('>H', int(i, 16)))[0]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeahh, but sorry for asking again, but i am making assumptions on what the function is doing, please correct me if im wrong. So, the explanation of the function, the first row is to split each 2 digits from the back of the interval (in this case, 4),, and what does [i:i+interval] mean? does it mean the length of the digits? 
and for the return, it unpacks the short of the pack int(i,16)? then change it to float for each i in splitted? 
thank you very very very much!!!!! I really appreciate it

Comment: In the first row, `range(0, len(hex(n)[2:]), interval)` may equals to `[0, 4, 8]` and `hex(n)[2:]` is `640761075D07` in this case. So, this row can be simply represented as `splitted = ['640761075D07'[i, i+4] for i in [0, 4, 8]]`. To split the given string `'640761075D07'` into `['6407', '6107, '5d07']`, you have to get sub-string by index `[i, i + interval]`.

Comment: The second row is about converting endianness. `unpack('<H', pack('>H', int('5d07', 16)))` will first convert `'5d07'` into `0x5d07` and converts it into `0x075d` again. Because `unpack()` returns a `set` of results, `unpack('<H', pack('>H', int('5d07', 16)))[0]` becomes 1885 (0x075d).